# Problema com limite de acesso por conta de refresh JAVASCRIPT

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Há alguma forma de retornar dados atualizados do servidor direto no **HTML** sem utilizar o `setInterval`, `setTimeout` essas coisas?

Porque essas funções esta desgastando do servidor.. Toda vez que ele da um *refresh* é como se estivesse tendo mais um acesso de um usuário no site, o que acaba estourando o limite de acessos diários no servidor.

Exemplo:

```
    var loop = setInterval;

    function setLoop(de, para, nome) {
       var url_s = $("#url_s").val();
       // $("._5chat").attr('id','chat_'+para);

       clearInterval(loop);
       loop = setInterval(function() {
           $("#mensChat div._5chat").load(url_s+'/demo/chat/test.php?de='+de+'&para='+para+'&url_s='+url_s)
       }, 1000);
    }

    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('.usuario').click(function() {
            setLoop($(this).attr('user-d'), $(this).attr('user-p'), $(this).attr('nome-p'));
        });
    });
```

Quando ele dar um *refresh* em 1000ms de tempo `setInterval` é como se o servidor recebesse mais um visitante...

Duas pessoas em **1hr** no site acho que é o suficiente para exceder o limite agora imagine o mundo...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cada requisição HTTP é uma nova requisição para o servidor. Só é possível "simular" sessões graças as linguagens server-side que dão suporte a isso, como é o caso do PHP. Mas isso só é uma requisição da "sessão atual" para o PHP, o servidor apache interpreta-a como uma nova requisição e não tem a "menor ideia" de que aquele usuário já estava "usando" os serviços.

Então duas pessoas usando o site por duas horas com o "refresh" de 1 segundo, **para o servidor serão 14400 requisições independentes e não há nada que possa ser feito quanto a isto**, exceto as seguintes soluções:

- Aumente o tempo de requisição (5s seria bom, mas depende da sua necessidade, no caso de um chat não é viável);
- Contrate uma hospedagem que tenha tráfego ilimitado. (Indispensável).

<sub>Uma observação interessante é que [ataques DoS](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ataque_de_nega%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_servi%C3%A7o) são bastante semelhantes ao que estava fazendo, exceto que eles veem em uma quantidade muito maior de requisições em um espaço de tempo muito menor. Ou seja, o seu próprio site estava "se atacando" e o motivo vem a seguir.</sub>

Outro problema é o uso da função `setInterval` que manda uma nova requisição antes mesma da anterior terminar (no caso de requisições assíncronas). Crie uma [função recursiva utilizando o `setTimeout`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/73697/8493) como já citado nos comentários pelo [Guilherme Nascimento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/3635/guilherme-nascimento).

```js
AtualizaDados = function(){
  var endereco = 'https://fiddle.jshell.net/';
  var params = {param1: 1, param2: 2};
  var time = 3000;
  var el = $("#mensChat div._5chat");

  $.ajax({
    url: endereco,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'html',
    data: params,
    success: function(html){
      el.html(html);
    },
    error: function(x, s){
      console.log(s, x);
    },
    complete: function(){
      setTimeout(AtualizaDados, time);
    }
  });
};

AtualizaDados();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="mensChat">
    <div class="_5chat"></div>
</div>
```

Uma boa prática também é diminuir a quantidade de dados a serem trafegados, ou seja, remova o "lixo" das suas requisições, passe a utilizar JSON para trafegar os dados, assim em vez de baixar o conteúdo HTML que teriam por exemplo de 300 a 500 bytes (cada carácter é um *byte*, inclusive espaços em branco ) teria apenas uns 80 a 120 *bytes* (dependendo do tamanho da mensagem), e então monte o HTML no lado do client, exemplo:

**Servidor:**

```
<?php

  /* Executa todas as ações necessárias */

  header('Content-Type: application/json');
  echo json_encode(Array(
     'autor' => $autor,
     'msg'   => $msg,
     'time'  => $time,
     'etc'   => $etc
  ));
  exit;
```

**Cliente:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

AtualizaDados = function(){
  var endereco = 'http://endereco/da/application/';
  var params = {param1: 1, param2: 2};
  var time = 3000;
  var el = $("#mensChat div._5chat");

  $.ajax({
    url: endereco,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: params,
    success: function(json){
      el.append(
        $('<div />').addClass('mensagem')
                    .append( $('<span />').addClass('autor').text( json.autor ) )
                    .append( $('<span />').addClass('msg').text( json.msg ) )
                    .append( $('<span />').addClass('hora').text( json.time ) );
      );
    },
    error: function(x, s){
      console.log(s, x);
    },
    complete: function(){
      setTimeout(AtualizaDados, time);
    }
  });
};

AtualizaDados();
```

Answer (score 3):

Como eu disse na outra resposta, `setInterval` não espera o load terminar, então use o `setTimeout`: [Carregar notificações de mensagem do ChatBox](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/73697/3635)

```
function setLoop(de, para, nome) {
   var url_s = $("#url_s").val();

   $("#mensChat div._5chat").load(url_s+'/demo/chat/test.php?de='+de+'&para='+para+'&url_s='+url_s,
       function() {
            setTimeout(function() {
                setLoop(de, para, nome);
            }, 1000);
       }
   );
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.usuario').click(function() {
        setLoop($(this).attr('user-d'), $(this).attr('user-p'), $(this).attr('nome-p'));
    });
});
```